# The First Lady's Dominos

Tags: riddle, visual, dominoes

I went to visit a friend the other day, and was invited inside.  When I entered, I spied an arrangement of various dominos, upon the table.  They were not arranged, standing up, as if she had been meaning to do anything spectacular with them, but the arrangement did seem to be important to her.  I inquired, of her, as to their meaning, but she simply smiled, and kept about her business.  Eventually, I let it go -- but I keep finding myself drawn to the sequence, as if it means something.

Do you think you could help me figure it out?

It looked like this:
[image: Domino Sequence]

## Hints (Added as needed):

## 1

> One time, upon the sea
>  I ordered a toody fruity
>  meal or three-ee

## 2

> I could add another tag to this question, but it would give it away.

## 3

> Something I should note.  This riddle is not nearly as complex as it seems.  A small group of children could possibly solve it.

## 4

> The number 14 has very little to do with this puzzle despite this sentence.

## 5

> My friend's first name is Ella.

## WARNING - SOLUTION BELOW

For anyone still trying to figure out how everything connects together, look at this.

> [image: Solution]

Comment: Is the answer only true for the time frame in which this puzzle was posted?

Comment: No, it's been "true" (for a lack of a better term), for a long time.

Comment: Today it is domino riddle day, I guess? ^^

Comment: @Varon I noticed that, too.  You'd think that it would have made it easier to find domino images.  After a while I gave up, and made my own, in MS paint.  LoL

Comment: If I only knew how dominos are related to [Plateau de fruits de mer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau_de_fruits_de_mer).

Comment: @Sleafar No plates of seafood involved =D

Comment: Does it start with an R?  If so I'll continue down that path. ;)

Comment: @Z.Dailey It does not.

Comment: Ok. New path then.

Comment: I actually just tested something with yours for another puzzle. And it works. :)

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Again a 14 words-hint. I think you want to tease me :D

Comment: I feel like I'm really close to this but the repeated emphasis on 14ness is telling me I'm wrong.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I hate you.

Comment: *snicker* Hahah, sorry =D

Comment: Okay - I do want to see this solved, so I'll add one last [probably] hint.

Comment: Oh, that hint throws out the line of reasoning I was using

Comment: Ugh, I know how to translate the dominos but I don't recognise the result.

Comment: @Zandar Oh?  [extra letters to fit the character limit]

Comment: Yeah.. it's easy to translate.. 5,5 3,4 5,3 ... HAHA. Maybe music notes? But I don't own 6 fingers per hand! Wait... A guitar has 6 Strings. Am I on the right way?

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Are we, uh, sure that this is a rebus

Comment: @question_asker I had thought so, based on the description in the tag - however, after looking it up, more in-depth, I'm not sure I agree.  I'm going to remove it, because I'm not sure that it belongs.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Thank you - I was beginning to wonder, since it seemed like decoding this was the correct route

Comment: Waiting for hint no. 6.. (and 7 - 20) :D

Comment: Hint: Current answers are too close to give further hints.

Comment: @Varon I actually have one more hint, in mind, but I'm worried that it might sound offensive.  Haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I think it's

> A-Tisket, A-Tasket

Some reasoning.

> Thanks to the partial answer by Zander, I found that the tune was in fact *A-Tisket, A-Tasket*, which was indeed covered by Ella Fitzgerald. It's also a nursery rhyme, thus the hint about a group of children. *Tisket* was also her propellent to national fame, which is why she smiled at in while you were there. For too long, I got hung up on the Fats Domino idea, and the only song she covered by him was *I'm Walkin'*, which sadly has no relationship with the tune outlined in the dominoes.

Comment: *her propellent to national fame* - Nice job.

Comment: It was also an arrangement, done by her, which is why I mentioned that the dominos were in an arrangement.  I'll add an image, to the bottom of the puzzle, now, that explains it for anyone still having trouble.

Answer (score 9):

## Partial answer

The first clue indicates

> a relationship between 1 and C ("one... sea"), 2 and D ("toody"), and 3 and E ("three-ee"). Given this, it seems likely that the numbers correspond to letters in the same order in the alphabet. A Caesar cipher doesn't produce a legible result, but there's another sequence of letters starting with C: a musical scale, with 1 being C and 6 being A (possibly 0 would be B, but it doesn't appear).

Using this, we can convert the dominoes to

> a sequence of notes: GGEFGEFGGEAGEEFFDEFFDDGFEDEC. Given the "first lady" in the title and the later hint about Ella, this is likely part of one of the songs of Ella Fitzgerald, as suggested by [Gamow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28925/12511) (possibly one of her collaborations with Fats Domino). Unfortunately, I don't recognise the tune when I hum it and I can't listen to her songs at the moment to check.

Comment: I love that someone got that clue. :) @Zandar

Answer (score 3):

## This is not the solution!!!

I staring hours to this and did heavy calculations and associations, but I got nothing. Here are some of my impressions:

**Positions**
I'm not sure if the position of the bottom elements <kbd>3 | 2</kbd>, <kbd>3 | 1</kbd> is important. (If it is a sequence, why they are not left aligned?)

**Math and Tables**

```
Decimal: 55, 34, 53, 45, 53, 65, 33, 44, 23, 44, 22, 54, 32, 31

HEX+DEC: E5, C4, E3, D5, E3, F5, C3, D4, B3, D4, B2, E4, C2, C1
  asDec: 229, 196, 227, 213, 227, 245, 195, 212, 179, 212, 178, 228, 194, 193

DEC+HEX: 5E, 3D, 5C, 4E, 5C, 6E, 3C, 4D, 2C, 4D, 2B, 5D, 3B, 3A
  asDec: 94, 61, 92, 78, 92, 110, 60, 77, 44, 77, 43, 93, 59, 58

HEX+HEX: EE, CD, EC, DE, EC, FE, CC, DD, BC, DD, BB, ED, CB, CA
  asDec: 238, 205, 236, 222, 236, 254, 204, 221, 188, 221, 187, 237, 203, 202
```

abs(d(x) - d(x+1)) `21, 19, 8, 8, 12, 32, 11, 21, 21, 22, 32, 22, 1`
If 32 is a space it could be a text
Other combinations I tried as well, but it ends up in a mess.

**Pure Number association**
I tried submarine numbers, president birthdays, game(i.e. soccer) scores, and so on

**Hints**
Both hints have 14 "words" like the number of tiles. Maybe it's only coincidence. But therefore it's to conspicuous to add `-ee` to the first hint.

Hint 2:
"I could `add a not-her tag` to this question, but it would `give it a way`"  Then it is not the First Lady but the president. (Obama?)

Hint 1:
"One time, up". - Is there something we have to set "up"-side?
"ordered" like "to sort"?

**Tags**
A "visual rebus" means no or not directly math. Perhaps I miss combinatoric. I don't know.

Comment: I was looking at the -ee the other day and thought the sentence might be an anagram and that was to signify dropping the ee. Because the typical spelling is tooty fruity.

Comment: Might also mean there are three sets of double e's in the answer.

Comment: @Varon You're giving me far too much credit.  Haha

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer perhaps

> Fats Domino

Argument:

> The hints are pointing at Ella Fitzgerald (the "First Lady of Song") and at Strange Fruit
>  Ella Fitzgerald won 14 Grammy awards

Comment: I'm afraid not.  Good try.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you mean

> Blue Monday. I don't have it handy to listen to.  Ella did a song called Blue Monday that I'm not familiar with. Fats Domino did a completely different song with the same title. I know the song by Fats and it's nothing like the notes in the puzzle but maybe it's the Ella song.